# How to display data fetched from NewsAPI into cards in another dart file in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-android

Here's `main.dart`

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AppName',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: SwipeFeedPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAPIState();
  }
}

class _MyAPIState extends State<MyAPI> {
  String getData = "";
  List getList = [];

  Future fetchData() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
    final data = await json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        getList = data["articles"];
        // log('data: $getList.toString()');
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("News"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(getList[10]["title"]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's `swipe_feed_page.dart`

```
class SwipeFeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwipeFeedPageState createState() => _SwipeFeedPageState();
}

class _SwipeFeedPageState extends State<SwipeFeedPage> {
  bool showAlignmentCards = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.grey)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer, color: Colors.grey)),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          showAlignmentCards
              ? CardsSectionAlignment(context)
              : CardsSectionDraggable()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here's `cards_section_alignment.dart`

```
List<Alignment> cardsAlign = [
  Alignment(0.0, 1.0),
  Alignment(0.0, 0.8),
  Alignment(0.0, 0.0)
];
List<Size> cardsSize = List(3);

class CardsSectionAlignment extends StatefulWidget {
  CardsSectionAlignment(BuildContext context) {
    cardsSize[0] = Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6);
    cardsSize[1] = Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55);
    cardsSize[2] = Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5);
  }

  @override
  _CardsSectionState createState() => _CardsSectionState();
}

class _CardsSectionState extends State<CardsSectionAlignment>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int cardsCounter = 0;

  List<ProfileCardAlignment> cards = List();
  AnimationController _controller;

  final Alignment defaultFrontCardAlign = Alignment(0.0, 0.0);
  Alignment frontCardAlign;
  double frontCardRot = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Init cards
    for (cardsCounter = 0; cardsCounter < 3; cardsCounter++) {
      cards.add(ProfileCardAlignment(cardsCounter));
    }

    frontCardAlign = cardsAlign[2];

    // Init the animation controller
    _controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700), vsync: this);
    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _controller.addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) changeCardsOrder();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        backCard(),
        middleCard(),
        frontCard(),

        // Prevent swiping if the cards are animating
        _controller.status != AnimationStatus.forward
            ? SizedBox.expand(
                child: GestureDetector(
                // While dragging the first card
                onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                  // Add what the user swiped in the last frame to the alignment of the card
                  setState(() {
                    // 20 is the "speed" at which moves the card
                    frontCardAlign = Alignment(
                        frontCardAlign.x +
                            20 *
                                details.delta.dx /
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        frontCardAlign.y +
                            40 *
                                details.delta.dy /
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);

                    frontCardRot = frontCardAlign.x; // * rotation speed;
                  });
                },
                // When releasing the first card
                onPanEnd: (_) {
                  // If the front card was swiped far enough to count as swiped
                  if (frontCardAlign.x > 3.0 || frontCardAlign.x < -3.0) {
                    animateCards();
                  } else {
                    // Return to the initial rotation and alignment
                    setState(() {
                      frontCardAlign = defaultFrontCardAlign;
                      frontCardRot = 0.0;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ))
            : Container(),
      ],
    ));
  }

  Widget backCard() {
    return Align(
      alignment: _controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward
          ? CardsAnimation.backCardAlignmentAnim(_controller).value
          : cardsAlign[0],
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
          size: _controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward
              ? CardsAnimation.backCardSizeAnim(_controller).value
              : cardsSize[2],
          child: cards[2]),
    );
  }

  Widget middleCard() {
    return Align(
      alignment: _controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward
          ? CardsAnimation.middleCardAlignmentAnim(_controller).value
          : cardsAlign[1],
      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
          size: _controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward
              ? CardsAnimation.middleCardSizeAnim(_controller).value
              : cardsSize[1],
          child: cards[1]),
    );
  }

  Widget frontCard() {
    return Align(
        alignment: _controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward
            ? CardsAnimation.frontCardDisappearAlignmentAnim(
                    _controller, frontCardAlign)
                .value
            : frontCardAlign,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: (pi / 180.0) * frontCardRot,
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(size: cardsSize[0], child: cards[0]),
        ));
  }

  void changeCardsOrder() {
    setState(() {
      // Swap cards (back card becomes the middle card; middle card becomes the front card, front card becomes a  bottom card)
      var temp = cards[0];
      cards[0] = cards[1];
      cards[1] = cards[2];
      cards[2] = temp;

      cards[2] = ProfileCardAlignment(cardsCounter);
      cardsCounter++;

      frontCardAlign = defaultFrontCardAlign;
      frontCardRot = 0.0;
    });
  }

  void animateCards() {
    _controller.stop();
    _controller.value = 0.0;
    _controller.forward();
  }
}

class CardsAnimation {
  static Animation<Alignment> backCardAlignmentAnim(
      AnimationController parent) {
    return AlignmentTween(begin: cardsAlign[0], end: cardsAlign[1]).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: parent, curve: Interval(0.4, 0.7, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
  }

  static Animation<Size> backCardSizeAnim(AnimationController parent) {
    return SizeTween(begin: cardsSize[2], end: cardsSize[1]).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: parent, curve: Interval(0.4, 0.7, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
  }

  static Animation<Alignment> middleCardAlignmentAnim(
      AnimationController parent) {
    return AlignmentTween(begin: cardsAlign[1], end: cardsAlign[2]).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: parent, curve: Interval(0.2, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
  }

  static Animation<Size> middleCardSizeAnim(AnimationController parent) {
    return SizeTween(begin: cardsSize[1], end: cardsSize[0]).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: parent, curve: Interval(0.2, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
  }

  static Animation<Alignment> frontCardDisappearAlignmentAnim(
      AnimationController parent, Alignment beginAlign) {
    return AlignmentTween(
            begin: beginAlign,
            end: Alignment(
                beginAlign.x > 0 ? beginAlign.x + 30.0 : beginAlign.x - 30.0,
                0.0) // Has swiped to the left or right?
            )
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: parent, curve: Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
  }
}
```

Here's `profile_card_alignment.dart`

```
class ProfileCardAlignment extends StatelessWidget {
  final int cardNum;
  ProfileCardAlignment(this.cardNum);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
              child: Image.asset('res/portrait.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox.expand(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black54],
                      begin: Alignment.center,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Headline $cardNum',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0)),
                    Text('A short description.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ],
                )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to show `Text(getList[index]["title"])` from `main.dart` in `Text('Headline')` of `profile_card_alignment.dart`. I'm quite new to `flutter` which is why I am finding it hard to figure this out.

Please help with this.

Comment: Hello. 
Obviously the file isn’t the issue here, your classes could be all in the same file, or one file for each class and you would just import them.    
You might want to create a specific widget that only fetches data and renders it to a list and compose it in the widget where you need it. 
The code you pasted is pretty lengthy to give you an example.

Comment: Also, don’t take it as critique but as constructive criticism but it looks like you didn’t go trough the basic concepts of widget composition and flutter development, I suggest you do that since widgets are pretty straightforward and easy to use and design once you get how they work!

Comment: @dev_mush please give an example

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can passing the api result into the targeted class. Many methods available to achieve that, you can look further into state management (eg. Provider, BLoC, GetX, etx).

Here is an example using plain http and singleton.

1. Create singleton service class eg. `request_service.dart`

```
class RequestService {
  /// private constructor
  RequestService._();

  /// the one and only instance of this singleton
  static final instance = RequestService._();

  Future<List<String>> fetchData() async {
    //do your api here using http or dio or anything
    return ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
  }
}
```

2. Get the api result inside initState in `cards_section_alignment.dart` and pass the value through class parameter

```
bool isLoading = true;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  requestData().then((value) {
    // Init cards
    for (cardsCounter = 0; cardsCounter < 3; cardsCounter++) {
      cards.add(
        ProfileCardAlignment(
          cardsCounter,
          tempWord: value[cardsCounter], //directly store the api result to object
        ),
      );
    }
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

3. Load your text from the object or class parameter in `profile_card_alignment.dart`

```
Text('Headline $cardNum ($tempWord)')
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/sahnamm/stackoverflow_74247625_answer), below is the result.

[image: sample]